# Where is the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Source Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I would like to extend the AWS PowerShell commands. Many of the AWS SDKs are on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/), for example [AWS .NET SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net), but not the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have found this already, but it is open source now 
https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell

Answer (score 2):

Windows PowerShell source for AWS is not open source.

You will find the **AWS Powershell** reference guide here
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html